# Mailgun inline image utf-8 png

Tags: python, png, inline, mailgun

I'm trying to get the inline image example from Mailgun to work with Python, but for some reason it throws a Unicode error when I add a png image. This is the example function that I'm using, with jpg changed to png.

```
def send_inline_image():
return requests.post(
    "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages",
    auth=("api", "YOUR_API_KEY"),
    files=[("inline", open("files/test.png"))],
    data={"from": "Excited User <YOU@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>",
          "to": "bar@example.com",
          "subject": "Hello",
          "text": "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!",
          "html": '<html>Inline image here: <img src="cid:test.png"></html>'})
```

This is the exception that's thrown:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Everything works as expected without the inline image. How can I get this to work with the png image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding 'rb' to your open() call:

`files=[("inline", open("files/test.png", 'rb'))]`

Comment: The image path is correct. `open("files/test.png").show()` throws an error `AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'show'` The open command only fails within requests. If it's run outside of the function it works. I'm not using the Image library currently. If this is required could you please explain your answer in more detail as to why this will work with .png, Requests and the Mailgun example. I tested the function with .jpg and it works, but not .png

Comment: sorry, it doesn't work with .jpg either. Both formats are throwing the error.

Comment: I tried just using 'rb' without the image library and it worked. E.g. `files=[("inline", open("files/test.png", 'rb'))]` If you want to edit your answer I'll accept it, so it's clear for other users.